# CoreData in SwiftUI: How to fetch a property distinctly?

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

I'm spending hours to figure out how to fetch values uniquely from a property of a data model (CoreData).

For example, if I have 3 records that have "Apple", "Banana" and "Apple" respectively in their wrappedName property, the ListView shows "Apple", "Banana" and "Apple" (3 rows).

But I want to show only "Apple" and "Banana" (2 rows).

How can I achieve this?

```
//ListView.swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ListView: View {
    @FetchRequest(entity: Data.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var data: FetchedResults<Data>    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { d in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ChartView(title: d.wrappedName) {
                        Text(d.wrappedName)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Data+CoreDataProperties.swift
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Data {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Data> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Data>(entityName: "Data")
    }

    @NSManaged public var date: Date?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    public var wrappedName: String {
        name ?? "Unknown"
    }

}
```

Comment: Helpful hint: change `extension Data` to `extension Data: Identifiable`, or even better add the single line `extension NSManagedObject: Identifiable {}` to conform all `NSManagedObject`s to the `Identifiable` protocol and you can change one line in your `List` view to `ForEach(data) { d in`. Not a huge improvement but nicer to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Custom `Notification` that sets a `Published` var would be better

```
public init() {
    self.uniqueDict = [NSDictionary]()

    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setUniqueDictValue), name: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: managedObjectContext)
    //set the uniqueDict variable
    setUniqueDictValue()
}

private func getEntityFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>
    {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName: "YourModel")

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType
        fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["name"]
        fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true

        return fetchRequest
    }
    ///Single Fetch of objects willSet uniqueDict variable
    func setUniqueDictValue()  {
        do {
            try self.uniqueDict = managedObjectContext.fetch(getEntityFetchRequest())
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch entity: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Distinct Results Sample Project
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xl3KVmBJrSg

Comment: @Ray after I answered this I made a little sample project and just uploaded a video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-U-4Zon6dbE

Comment: Went through your tutorial!
But to use `fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true` it requires `fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType` but then I got error 'NSFetchedResultsController does not support both change tracking and fetch request's with NSDictionaryResultType'.
Could you give me advice?

Comment: Because switching it to a Dictionary it means that you are no longer getting an array of objects you are getting a dictionary of "wrappedName"/String. The 'fetchController!.delegate = self' line needs to be removed. Every time you want a new list you have to trigger the initFetchedResultsController() method. In the ViewModel ADD '@Published var uniqueDict: [NSDictionary]', to init() add 'self.uniqueDict = [NSDictionary]()', Change all 'YourModel' too 'NSDictionary'. In ListView change 'List(viewModel.uniqueDict, id: \.self){obj in Text((obj as NSDictionary).allValues.first as! String)}'

Comment: Here is another sample project https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xl3KVmBJrSg

Comment: Without `controllerDidChangeContent` the ListView is not updated when new data is added from other views... But it makes using `returnsDistinctResults` impossible... I guess I need to take a different approach until `@FetchRequest` supports distinct results. Thanks for your detailed instructions tho!

Comment: I've been thinking about this since I noticed that. You can also setup a Notification in the init(). See in the code. The trigger will come from the Notification vs manually

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Core Data model. The model should be designed how you want to display it in your UI. Don't design it like it is a database.

In your case an another Entity called Fruit, with an int fruitType that is a unique key, 1 for Apple and 2 for Banana. In your Data entity have a relation fruit but instead of fetching Data now fetch for Fruit. If you want to show something about Data in your list cell then simply add a property to the Fruit class to retrieve it from the related datas. And using KVO observing you can make it so the context detects a change to Fruit when something in its related Data changes.